# Как настроить минимальный margin

Tags: html, css

Как можно настроить минимальный margin с процентами ? не просто 5%  а что бы например минимальный был 40 пикселей(при ширине окна  1000 пикселей) а при ширине окна например 1150 пикселей  марджин должен быть 4,7% например. Кароче нужно что бы марджин меньше 40 пикселей ни при каких обстоятельствах не был

Comment: `margin-left: max(40px, 4.7vw);` например

Comment: Оно самое ,спасибо